# I get java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect when launching tomcat server in eclipse

Tags: windows-10, tomcat7, java-7, permission-denied, eclipse-luna

This problem occurs on a in-house customized version of Eclipse Luna with Jdk 1.7.161_1_win and tomcat 7.0.64_4 on the Windows 10 platform.

Background:

tomcat server originally launched fine. Then last May we started having Permission Denied issues on Windows 10, but not on Mac. The issue was fixed on Windows 10 by adding the directives

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false

For a few weeks this solved the problem, but then the problem resurfaced. We were not able to find a fix and we moved on to starting the app on Mac (High Sierra, same jdk, same tomcat, same directives) . It started on Mac just fine

Later we realized the starting the tomcat sever using the tomcat7 plugin with the goal tomcat7:run-war-only maven plugin works fine with no Permission Denied issues on Windows 10. So it seems there is an issue with eclipse Luna bringing up tomcat 7 on Windows 10 and jdk 7 that causes this problem.

Any body has seen this issue before?

Please note that as I said we tried the

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false

but it is no longer fixing the problem.

One more piece of information to add is that this problem did not occur on one of our developer windows 10 boxes until a month ago on Windows 10, but as of a month ago he started having the same problem on his Windows 10 box.

Comment: Stacktrace for completeness

java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
 at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_161]
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_161]
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_161]
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_161]
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.7.0_161]

Comment: at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.7.0_161]
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:580) ~[na:1.7.0_161]
 at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]

Comment: at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]

Comment: at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[dialogflow-shaded-0.72.0.jar:na]